# Removing if element has an specific data value jquery

Tags: jquery

**EXPECTED**

When clicking on `button` I want it to alert the data-type value

**HTML**

```
<ul id="threads">
 <li data-href='q' data-type='m'>abc <button>Click</button></li>
 <li data-href='q' data-type='t'>mnp <button>Click</button></li>
 <li data-href='r' data-type='t'>rst <button>Click</button></li>
 </ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
   $(document).on("click","button",function(){


  var  element = $(document).find("div").find("[data-href='q']");

   if(element....has data-type='m'?){alert("this is m type"); }
  if(element....has data-type='t'?){alert("this is t type"); }



    })
```

This is taking me more time than expected, does anyone knows the way to go?

Comment: Why are you not looking up `$('#threads')` before you find the li's that have the data element?

Comment: ok..just dont know....how do I select `data-type='m'` instead of `data-type='t'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#threads button").click(function(){
  var datatype = $(this).parent().attr("data-type");
  if(datatype == 'm'){
   alert(datatype);
  }else{
   alert(datatype);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="threads">
 <li data-href='q' data-type='m'>abc <button>Click</button></li>
 <li data-href='q' data-type='t'>mnp <button>Click</button></li>
 <li data-href='r' data-type='t'>rst <button>Click</button></li>
 </ul>
```

I think this method will helps you lot

Comment: Yes! this is how I eventually decided to make my code. I already knew it, but I think your approach is very nice & clean. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#threads').find('li').filter("[data-href='q'][data-type='m']").remove();
```

Find the parent by id, find the nested lis, then filter those that have both a q and an m, and remove them/it.

As to why I have the selector broken up into three steps, you can refer to http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/ for more reading.

Here is an alternate version using a conditional.

```
var $threadItems = $('#threads').find('li');

$threadItems.each(function(index, item){
    var $item = $(item);

    if ($item.data('href') === 'q') {
        if ($item.data('type') === 'm') {
            $item.remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: awesome approach.

Comment: Shouldn't one of those data attributes be `data-type`?

Comment: I was actually lookinf for a way where it be done by using `if clause`, for example...`if(...='m'){remove();}`

Comment: Selectors are essentially if conditionals.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use an (apparently unnecessary) `if` statement? Perhaps in an edit to your question for the benefit of others reading the question, and trying to help, in future.

Comment: ok, I edited it.@Taplar approach was a good way to go, bu I need to use an if statement

Comment: @joe added a conditional example

Comment: thank you taplar,  this was the line I was looking for to complete my code `$item.data('type') === 'm'` it works perfect. +1!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#threads li[data-href='q'][data-type='m']").remove();
```

Comment: You have two data attributes sharing the same name, one of them should be `data-type`, exactly as with Taplar's original approach. Incidentally while this code may (when corrected) solve the problem, what do you expect the OP to learn given that you've explained nothing about your answer?

Comment: @DavidThomas thank you, I copied that from his earlier version :)